# Classicthesis formatting for one-sided printing

Tags: margins, classicthesis

I'm planning to use the [`classicthesis`](http://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/) package for typesetting my PhD, however the university regulations dictate that it must be printed one-sided.  Is there a way of configuring `classicthesis`, such that the left margin is always the inner and the right margin the outer?  The default behaviour of alternating inner and outer margins looks very odd when printed single-sided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this really related to the `classicthesis` package? It should depend on the document class you use. Try to add the option `oneside` to your document class command.

Comment: Stephan, you are correct.  The declaration of the classicthesis document type includes twoside as a default option.  I have changed this and all is well. Thanks.